Polars out of memory on join
Wondering if anyone has seen similar in Polars and what the options are:
df1 = pl.scan_parquet("output_data/tmpbase.parquet").cast({"owning_account_id": pl.Categorical}).sort("owning_account_id")
df2 = pl.scan_parquet("output_data/tmpintermediate.parquet").cast({"transaction_id": pl.Categorical}).sort("transaction_id")
df1.join(
    df2,
    on=["owning_account_id", "transaction_id"],
    how="inner",
).sink_parquet("output_data/table.parquet")

This runs but runs out of memory pretty quickly using a lazyframe on my Mac. Basically it fills up the ram, then spills to swap then dies when the swap hits 90GB. But a join, I believe is supposed to be streaming compliant, and work with stuff not fitting in memory, so I'm clearly missing something there.

Try taking out both the cast to categorical and the sort.

Can you provide the dtypes of owning_account_id and transaction_id?

I think the sorting is an issue too, maybe it makes sense to inspect the query plan. Also, e.g. if it uses hash join, I think there is a data structure needed in memory (hash table) even in streaming mode. I experienced OOM with unique , sort and join operations when having a huge number of unique values in the specified columns.

Thanks chaps. We found that if we moved from an inner join to a left join then it ran absolutely fine. So we did that then filtered out the remaining values and everything then comfortably ran in memory, like 20GB usage rather than 90GB+...

We found that if we moved from an inner join to a left join the ram usage dropped from 90+GB and an OOM to less than 20GB and actually finishing. So doing that and then filtering the remaining right side of the join worked well for us.
Details in this issue: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/15771

As was mentioned in the comments, casting to categorical may solve it. I assume your owning_account_id and your transaction_id are strings. If they aren't you'll need to cast them to strings before casting them to categorical. Here is an example with 5 million rows in both dataframes and it runs without any issues:
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
num_records = 5000000 

dates_df1 = np.random.choice(pd.date_range('20210101', periods=1000), num_records)
product_ids_df1 = np.random.choice(np.arange(10000, 20000), num_records)
quantities_df1 = np.random.randint(1, 100, num_records)
prices_df1 = np.random.uniform(10, 500, num_records)

df1 = pl.DataFrame({
    'transaction_id': np.arange(num_records).astype(str),  
    'date': dates_df1,
    'product_id': product_ids_df1.astype(str),  
    'quantity': quantities_df1,
    'price_per_unit': prices_df1
})

dates_df2 = np.random.choice(pd.date_range('20210101', periods=1000), num_records)
product_ids_df2 = np.random.choice(np.arange(10000, 20000), num_records)
amounts_df2 = np.random.uniform(1000, 5000, num_records)

df2 = pl.DataFrame({
    'transaction_id': np.arange(num_records).astype(str),  
    'product_id': product_ids_df2.astype(str),  
    'amount': amounts_df2
})

df1.write_parquet('large_dataset1.parquet')
df2.write_parquet('large_dataset2.parquet')

df1 = pl.scan_parquet("large_dataset1.parquet")
df2 = pl.scan_parquet("large_dataset2.parquet")

result = df1.join(
    df2,
    on=["transaction_id","product_id"],  
    how="inner"
)

result.collect().write_parquet("table.parquet")


Hey Serge, thanks for this sorry I didn't reply. I tried that and it made some difference but it still blew up. I found actually that the inner join was stopping it spilling to disk for some reason, but flipping it to a left join and filtering the otherside after worked fine. Details here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/15771
